# Wordpress / Nginx Permalink

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I use

> try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

which normaly works fine but in this case it works only for posts, for categories I get 404 error.

Its not theme issue because same is happening with the default theme.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

i've a full guide here for setting up nginx and WordPress

http://themesforge.com/featured/high-performance-wordpress-part-3/

hope this helps,

Ed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.